# NMAP shows open ports even tough I installed the UFW firewall

Tags: firewall, nmap, ufw

I have a VServer, in which I installed the firewall UFW. I scanned the Server with NMAP but I it showed a lot open Ports, which I didnt open. Is it a Bug? Or did I installed UFW false?
Thank you

ufw status:
http://prntscr.com/pgp5db
nmap:
nmap -T4 -A -v *********

//edit I solved the problem. The Problem was I just used the wrong nmap command. So the ports where already closed.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the following: 1) instead of posting a screenshot of terminal output, add the actual output; 2) we need the output of the `nmap` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing UFW and activating the systems unit is not sufficient.
You need to configure it.
The normal default is that everything is denied and UFW therefore disabled after installation (including start of service).
Check `ufw status` output and be careful not to enable the firewall configuration via UFW or other means without ensuring You have access with SSH or what You need to manage Your server.